# Understanding scope in ruby block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, prawn

I'm using the Prawn gem to write to PDF. I have started an action to write the PDF but I don't understand how to use my data in the right way. I have:

```
def download
  @bid = Bid.find(params[:bid_id])
  @title = @bid.bid_title.gsub(/\s+/, "")

  Prawn::Document.generate("#{@title}.pdf") do
    text @bid.client_name
  end
end
```

Where I add the text, the Bid is nil. How do I use the `@bid` that I created before in the block below?

Comment: Try this `@bid = Bid.try(params[:bid_id])`

Comment: Your syntax looks correct, are you sure you're returning a `@bid` item from your `Bid.find`? are you sure that the `.client_name` of this object is not nil?

Comment: @Pavan Bid is being set just fine. It's inside the lower block that it is being flagged as nil.

Comment: @MikeH-R Yes, Bid is being set. I'm reading something about instance variables not being accessible when running the block with instance_eval. It "runs the block in the context of a different instance." I don't fully understand it and I'm not sure if this is the issue.

Comment: Can you paste the exact error you are getting?

Comment: @Jordy, I was just looking at my own code and you could just have a local variable named bid as well `bid = @bid` because that definitely works in my prawn code. Unsure why there should be a problem with those variables though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is often useful to dug into source code to understand how all the magic works.

If we consider [Prawn source code](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/blob/master/lib/prawn/document.rb), we can see that in method `self.generate(filename, options = {}, &block)` our block is transmitted to Prawn::Document.new method. Hence, we shall consider Prawn::Document `initialize` method. There we can see the following code:

```
if block
  block.arity < 1 ? instance_eval(&block) : block[self]
end

#arity is a number of block arguments.  
# block[self] is a block.call(self)
```

If we simplify Prawn source code, we can mock this situation in order to understand it better:

```
module Prawn 
  class Document
    def self.generate(filename, &block)
      block.arity < 1 ? instance_eval(&block) : block[self]
    end
  end
end

class A
  def initialize
    @a = 1
  end

  def foo
    qwe = 1
    Prawn::Document.generate("foobar") do 
      p @a
      p qwe
      p instance_variables  
    end
  end
end

A.new.foo

# Output:
     nil # @a
     1   # qwe
     []  # there is no instance_variables
```

But if we provide an argument for our block, another condition in generate will be called (block[self] instead of instance_eval):

```
module Prawn 
  class Document
    def self.generate(filename, &block)
      block.arity < 1 ? instance_eval(&block) : block[self]
    end
  end
end

class A
  def initialize
    @a = 1
  end

  def foo
    qwe = 1
    Prawn::Document.generate("foobar") do |whatever|
      p @a
      p qwe
      p instance_variables  
    end
  end
end

A.new.foo

# Output
  1     # @a
  1     # qwe
  [:@a] # instance_variables
```

So in your situation this code will work I think:

```
def download
  @bid = Bid.find(params[:bid_id])
  @title = @bid.bid_title.gsub(/\s+/, "")

  Prawn::Document.generate("#{@title}.pdf") do |ignored|
    text @bid.client_name
  end
end
```

or

```
def download
  bid = Bid.find(params[:bid_id])
  title = @bid.bid_title.gsub(/\s+/, "")

  Prawn::Document.generate("#{title}.pdf") do
    text bid.client_name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `Prawn::Document.generate` evaluates the block in the context of a Prawn::Document instance. This means that instance variables in the block will be resolved as instance variables of the Prawn::Document object, since that is `self` in the context of the block.

To make this work, use local variables instead of (or in addition to) instance variables.